# how to identify the long classname using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Can anyone tell how to identify the following element in selenium `webdriver` ::

```
<section id="reports" class="landing-page-column ng-scope" ng-if="requestsForReview &amp;&amp; requestsForReview != 'null' &amp;&amp; requestsForReview.length > 0">
```

Tried this but it failed in all the instance ::

```
final WebElement pendingrequestcolumn = insidepage.findElement(By.id("section#reports.landing-page-column.ng-scope"));
```

Comment: @kotoj <section id="reports" class="landing-page-column ng-scope" ng-if="requestsForReview &amp;&amp; requestsForReview != 'null' &amp;&amp; requestsForReview.length > 0">

Comment: Pease update your question with html and proper formatting and actual selectors you use

Comment: <section id="reports" class="landing-page-column ng-scope" ng-if="requestsForReview &amp;&amp; requestsForReview != 'null' &amp;&amp; requestsForReview.length > 0">

Comment: Pease update your question with html and proper formatting and actual selectors you use - once again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the below locators can be of help

```
//section[@id='reports' and @class='landing-page-column ng-scope'] - Using AND 

//section[@id='reports' or @class='landing-page-column ng-scope'] - Using OR

//section[contains(@ng-if,'requestsForReview')] - using contains

(//section[@id='reports'])[0] - using Index, starts from 0.Trying changing index value
```

**eg: (//section[@id='reports'])[X]**

Here X takes index value.

Answer (score 2):

The locator which you have mentioned is not id. You need to use `By.cssSelector` instead of `By.id`

Comment: i tried with cssSelector as well but it doesnt work out. in the question it was by mistake i wrote id but i use cssSelector.

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"section#reports.landing-page-column.ng-scope"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: try using `By.id("reports")`

Comment: its not able to identify reports as well :(

Answer (score 1):

In HTML I can see that this element has `id=reports`, so `By.id("reports")` should do the work.

Comment: Have you tried using xpath to get this element?
E.g. `By.xpath("//section[@id='reports']")`

Comment: tried using the xpath as well but its saying unable to identify

Comment: You can also try to use explicit wait to find that element. Use `(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//section[@id='reports']")))`. 
See WebDriver docs for more info: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits